# Can a VGA monitor be used with a 16-bit console?

Tags: pc, hardware, monitor, sega-genesis

Planning to buy this bad boy - [**Sega Mega Drive II**](https://www.flipkart.com/aoko-16-bit-sega-tv-video-game-350-built-in-games-mortal-kombat-cassete-limited/p/itmfc7dca7c923d7)

**The problem**: Not sure if it will work with my VGA Monitor. Don't have a TV.

I'm assuming it would work if I buy this **[AV 2 VGA Converter](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B08R7P4PDN/ref=cm_sw_r_apan_i_HWS2JYTZ67ENT3T581YW?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1)** and connect the two.

I have Acer V193HQV monitor with supports a max resolution of 1366x768 pixels.

Thoughts?